Integral of a Contour with Inner Loop
Problem. Let
$$
            g(x+iy) = \left[ \frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2} + \frac{y-1}{(x+1)^2 + (y-1)^2} \right] +i \left[ \frac{x+1}{(x+1)^2 + (y-1)^2} + \frac{x-y}{x^2 + y^2} \right] 
        $$ and
$$ f(x+iy) = 
        \begin{cases}
            x^2 - y^2 + i(1+2xy) & \text{if } |x+iy| \le 1 \\
            g(x+iy) & \text{if } |x+iy|>1 \text{ and } x+iy \neq -1+i \\
            -1 + i & \text{if } x+iy = -1+i
        \end{cases}
        $$
Evaluate: $\displaystyle \int_{C} \frac{(\cos z)f(z)}{(4z^2 - 4iz -1)^2} dz $ where $C = C_{3} + C_{4}$ such that $C_{3}: r=1-2\sin \theta, \theta \in [0,\pi]$ and $C_{4}: z= e^{i\theta}, \theta \in [\pi,2\pi]$
Attempt. I first notice that the integrand function has a pole at $z=i/2$ with multiplicity 4. Since this pole is outside $C$, I'm anticipating to use Cauchy-Goursat Theorem. But the problem is $C$ is not a simple closed contour, and I'm not sure what to do if $C$ has an inner loop from the limaçon $C_3$. But then I also thought that we can consider $C_3 - C_4$ which is a simple closed contour so that $\displaystyle \int_{C} \frac{(\cos z)f(z)}{(4z^2 - 4iz -1)^2} dz = 2\int_{C_4} \frac{(\cos z)f(z)}{(4z^2 - 4iz -1)^2} dz $. How should I proceed?
